# QtCreator: deploying Android app to different location

Tags: android, qt, deployment, android-ndk, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator 3.3.2 on Windows, and I'm developing a QML/C++ app on Android.

By default, the app is deployed to "/data/data/..." on Android. I'd like it to be deployed to a different location, though I can't find any option/documentation on how to do so.

I know there's a binary called "androiddeployqt" that controls the deployment to Android, but I can't find any *good* documentation on how to customize its behavior.